# How to forecast time series using AutoReg in python

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima, autoregressive-models

I'm trying to build old school model using only auto regression algorithm. I found out that there's an implementation of it in `statsmodel` package. I've read the documentation, and as I understand it should work as ARIMA. So, here's my code:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.tsa.AutoReg(df_train.beer, 12).fit()
```

And when I want to predict new values, I'm trying to follow the documentation:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(start=df_test.index.min(), end=df_test.index.max())
# or
y_pred = model.predict(start=100, end=1000)
```

Both returns a list of NaNs.

Also, when I type `model.predict(0, df_train.size - 1)` it predicts real values, but `model.predict(0, df_train.size)` predicts NaNs list.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

**P.S.** I know there's ARIMA, ARMA or SARIMAX algorithms, that can be used as basic auto regression. But I need exactly AutoReg.

Answer (score 4):

We can do the forecasting in couple of ways:

1. by directly using the `predict()` function and
2. by using the definition of *AR(p)* process and the parameters learnt with `AutoReg()`: this will be helpful for short-term predictions, as we shall see.

[image]

Let's start with a sample dataset from `statsmodels`, the data looks like the following:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data['SUNACTIVITY']
plt.plot(range(len(data)), data)
```

[image]

Let's fit an *AR(p)* process to model the time series and use partial autocorrelation plot to find the order *p*, as shown below

[image: sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(data, lags=30, method="ywm")]

As seen from above, the first few *PACF* values remain significant, let's use *p=10* for the *AR(p)*.

Let's divide the data into training and validation (test) datasets and fit auto-regressive model of order 10 using the training data:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
n = len(data)
ntrain = int(n*0.9)
ntest = n - ntrain
lag = 10
res = AutoReg(data[:ntrain], lags = lag).fit()
```

Now, use the `predict()` function for forecasting all values corresponding to the held-out dataset:

```
preds = res.model.predict(res.params, start=n-ntest, end=n)
```

Notice that we can get the exactly same predictions using the parameters from the trained model, as shown below:

```
x = data[ntrain-lag:ntrain].values
preds1 = []
for t in range(ntrain, n):
    pred = res.params[0] + np.sum(res.params[1:]*x[::-1])
    x[:lag-1], x[lag-1] = x[-(lag-1):], pred
    preds1.append(pred)
```

Note that the forecast values generated this way is same as the ones obtained using the `predict()` function above.

```
np.allclose(preds.values, np.array(preds1))
# True
```

Now, let's plot the forecast values for the test data:

[image]

As can be seen, for long term prediction, quality of forecasting is not that good (since the forecasted values are used for long term prediction).

Let's instead go for short-term predictions now and use the last *lag* points from the dataset to forecast the next value, as shown in the next code snippet.

```
preds = []
for t in range(ntrain, n):
    pred = res.params[0] + np.sum(res.params[1:]*data[t-lag:t].values[::-1])
    preds.append(pred)
```

As can be seen from the next plot, short term forecasting works way better:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full code please with the plotting?

Comment: Maybe it works better because you are leaking the test set to predictions in here: np.sum(res.params[1:]*data[t-lag:t].values[::-1])?

Comment: @Sandipan Dey How is this answer related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for forecasting

```py
import statsmodels as sm

model = sm.tsa.AutoReg(df_train.beer, 12).fit()
y_pred = model.model.predict(model.params, start=df_test.index.min(), end=df_test.index.max())
```

Comment: This makes no sense. What if data doesn't have an index? Also this is identical to the original question.

Answer (score -2):

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

model=AutoReg(dataset[''],lags=1)
ARFit=model.fit()
forecasted=ARFit.predict(start=len(dataset),end=len(dataset)+12)

#visualizacion
dataset[''].plot(figsize=(12,8),legend=True)
forecasted.plot(legend=True)
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32572291)